MUI Datagrid - The whole table is rendered when a row is selected
This is my basic mui datagrid:

import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { DataGrid, GridColDef, GridRowSelectionModel } from '@mui/x-data-grid';

export default function DataGridDemo() {
  const [rowSelectionModel, setRowSelectionModel] = React.useState<GridRowSelectionModel>([]);

    const handleRowSelectionModelChange = React.useCallback((newRowSelectionModel: GridRowSelectionModel) => {
      setRowSelectionModel(newRowSelectionModel);
    }, []);
    console.log("DataGrid");
  return (
    <Box sx={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        initialState={{
          pagination: {
            paginationModel: {
              pageSize: 5,
            },
          },
        }}
        onRowSelectionModelChange={handleRowSelectionModelChange}
        pageSizeOptions={[5]}
        checkboxSelection
        disableRowSelectionOnClick
      />
    </Box>
  );
}

In this code, selecting a row causes the entire table to re-render. Removing the onRowSelectionModelChange prop prevents this re-rendering, but it also removes the ability to save the selected rows. I'd like to avoid re-rendering the table while still being able to store the selected rows.
